# No module named `foo` - when foo.exe built from foo.py, imports bar which imports foo

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-importlib

I built a tkinter application (let's call it `foo.py`) and packaged it as a onefile executable (`foo.exe`). Within `foo.py`, there is a function (`func_load_scripts`) that uses `importlib.import_module()` to import all `.py` files in a specific folder. (e.g. Suppose there is a `bar.py` in `C:\foobar\`).

1. When I run `foo.exe`, `func_load_scripts` runs and it imports `bar.py`.
2. What I have noticed is that if it is a standard library, generally no issues.
3. Suppose `apple` is a third-party module, if both `foo.py` and `bar.py` have `import apple`, there is no issue too.
4. If `foo.py` doesn't have `import apple`, but `bar.py` has `import apple`, there will be a *ModuleNotFoundError* (kind of understandable...)
5. When `bar.py` contains `import foo`, there will be a *ModuleNotFoundError* too.

**Doubt 1**: Why can't `bar.py` import `foo.py`? (I believe it is because bar is looking for foo.py in the PYTHONPATH... and it it doesn't exist. I tried adding `sys._MEIPASS` (using `sys.path.insert()`) and it doesn't work too. It is probably because foo.py is not longer available, which is the purpose of packaging it as an executable in the first place.)

**Motivation**: I want to expose some (i.e. not all) functions/classes within `foo.py` to the user. Hence, it will be good to allow them to use `from foo import func_one`.

Because `bar.py` cannot have the `import foo`, I created a separate file to house the common functions and classes that I want to expose to users and named this as `common.py`. Next, in both `foo.py` and `bar.py`, I have `import common` (hence satisfying #3 above)

**Question**: Is this a good workaround? Is there some alternative method that users can probe and figure out other functions, classes, constants that I have in `foo.py`? Will they be able to `import foo` through some means?

Apologies for the long question.

Here's a small reproducible code which describes the problem.

```
#foo.py
import importlib
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, os.getcwd())

def func_one():
    print('This is foo.py')

def func_load_scripts():
    try:
        mod = importlib.import_module('bar')
    except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
        print(err)
    else:
        print(dir(mod))
    finally:
        input('Press any key to exit...')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_one()
    func_load_scripts()
```

```
#bar.py
import foo

def func_two():
    print('We are in `bar.py`...')
    foo.func_one()
```

Error message when I run `foo.exe` with `bar.py` in the same folder.

[image: No module named 'foo']

To package as exe: `pyinstaller --onefile foo.py`

Comment: When `foo.py` is your main module, the module name is `__main__`, not `foo`. It's only `foo` when it's loaded with `import foo`. Think about making a separate module with nothing but your main function that doesn't need to be imported by anything else.

Comment: (I also generally don't recommend using importlib or sys.path modifications and pyinstaller together at all; one component that makes a bunch of assumptions and performs magic based on those assumptions is enough; when you have two such components, you get places where the assumptions conflict with each other, like here).

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I'll try based on your inputs.